# C# PostAsync to Laravel Passport says Authorization server does not support grant

Tags: c#, laravel, laravel-passport

I'm trying to request a token from Passport, via C#, like so:

```
StringContent content = new StringContent("form_params: [{'grant_type':'password', 'username': "+UserName.Text+",'password':"+Password.Password+ ",'client_id':4,'client_secret':'YAYLOOKATTHISNOTWORKING','scope':''}]", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
HttpResponseMessage response = await App.client.PostAsync("https://" + InterfaceAddress.Text+"/oauth/token", content);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();    // Throw if not a success code.
```

This always results in a `The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server.` error. The passpport client was created with `--password`.

Comment: Have you seen what the raw request looks like? Have you tried building the request in postman (or a similar tool) to verify you're getting the same result from a different client?

Comment: The type of the content says `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but the content looks more like JSON. recheck how you are sending the content as that may be the problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The media type of the `content` says `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but the actual content string looks more like JSON.

Recheck how you are sending the content as this may be a formatting problem.

Based on [API documentation for requesting password grant token](https://laravel.com/docs/master/passport#requesting-password-grant-tokens), a password grant token request would look like this

```
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $http->post('http://your-app.com/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => 'client-id',
        'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
        'username' => 'taylor@laravel.com',
        'password' => 'my-password',
        'scope' => '',
    ],
]);
```

[Guzzel documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#sending-form-fields)

> Sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST requests requires that you specify the POST fields as an array in the `form_params` request options.
>
> ```
> $response = $client->request('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', [
>     'form_params' => [
>         'field_name' => 'abc',
>         'other_field' => '123',
>         'nested_field' => [
>             'nested' => 'hello'
>         ]
>     ]
> ]);
> ```

The following shows how to make the password grant token request using `HttpClient` and `FormUrlEncodedContent`

```
var url = "https://" + InterfaceAddress.Text + "/oauth/token";
string username = UserName.Text;
string password =  Password.Password;

var form_params = new Dictionary<string,string>(){
    {"grant_type", "password"},
    {"username", username},
    {"password", password},
    {"client_id","4"},
    {"client_secret", "YAYLOOKATTHISNOTWORKING"},
    {"scope", ""}
};
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(form_params);    
var response = await App.client.PostAsync(url, content);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();    // Throw if not a success code.
```